# Has anybody integrated craft with a rewards system?

Tags: plugins, ecommerce

Just wondered if anybody had done anything like this? Perhaps through zapier or a custom inetgration? Customers earning points or discounts through a Craft e-commerce site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a plugin, but there's numerous jQuery or SaaS products that achieve this.

For a Craft Plugin, you could hook onto the after purchase event and add a set amount of score to a user field.

e.g. if our field was `score`, after purchase we could add `+30` to the score field. Then assign discounts based on the `score` field. e.g. if `$score > 30` assign 30% discount to products.

For integrations, you could easily just listen for the event and send some data via a `PUT` request to a third-party system.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer thats really useful